# Video Editor that can import Photoshop PSD files and overlay them on video with transparent channel?

Tags: software, windows

I am using Magix Movie Edit Pro for about 10 years because it has one feature that I use all the time: Being able to import Photoshop files (PSD) with transparent channels into the video and overlaying the video clip.

However, all versions of the software were buggy (video format could not be read anymore by an update, software often crashed while doing simple video cuts, even the 2020 version crashes when simply opening the MVP project file).

To get rid of this annoying and time-extensive instability, I would love to use an alternative video editing software.

I have seen that Adobe Premiere and After Effects have the feature of importing PSD files, but I have never worked with the programs because they looks complicated and seem pricy.

The video editing software should be simple to use. I don't need any effects. Just fade-in and fade-out, and PSD files with transparency. Multiple tracks and separate audio track.

Operating system: Windows 10.

Thanks for any tips.

**Update:** I have tried myself the following video editors, here are the results:

Cannot import PSD files:

- DaVinci Resolve
- HitFilm Express ("File not supported")
- Lightworks
- Olive
- Power Director
- Shotcut

Can import PSD files (but not handle them):

- Blender (shows up in the tracks but not showing up as overlay)
- KdenLive (shows up in the tracks but not showing up as overlay)

Can import and display PSD files:

- Adobe After Effects
- Adobe Premiere Pro
- FilmoraPro
- Magix Movie Edit Pro
- Sony Vegas Pro (is Magix company)

Comment: .PSD is a proprietary image format, which Adobe owns.  If you want interoperability outside the Adobe suite, use a non-proprietary format, such as   OpenEXR (which supports transparency, layers, 8,16, 32 bits).  If you don't need multiple layers, .png's also support transparency.

Comment: Also, Davinci Resolve does support .psd.  I just tried it.  It works.

Comment: ...and it does support transparency.  You might need to adjust the premultiplication of alpha channels, if you had troubles in the past, but that's the same for any software.